# How to achieve fadeout stickyheader in recyclerview like whatsapp or skype?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to fadeout a visible date header at top after scrolling a recyclerview. I have achieved a sticky date header by using stickyHeaderRecyclerview library but want to achieve fadeout(visibility gone after 2 secs) the first visible header in a recyclerview?

Tried some sticky header libraries but not able to achieve my requirement.

Take below image for your reference.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3XzS.jpg)

Comment: `I want to fadeout a first visible date header at top in a stickyheaderecyclerview lib` could you translate this to a human readable English sentence?

Comment: @Zun Sorry for my bad english. I want to show a date separator like how whatsapp is showing. Please check the image i have attached for your reference.

Comment: Hello Indirajith, welcome to Stack Overflow; You're going to have to provide a little bit more info about what you've tried and what you haven't. If you're in doubt, please don't hesitate reading [the Help section about questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In short, SO will rarely give you good answers if all you say is "I want to do X how can I do X". Rather, users tend to prefer a smaller scope: "I am trying to do X, I've tried to do this, this and that, but instead of ZZ happening, I see YY, any idea? Log says this:xxxx" etc. You get the idea. Good luck! :)